# Find The shortest Path between Given multiple Nodes

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to find the Shortest Path between given Multiple Nodes.
Like I have an Array of locations Node and then there is a location for the user. I want to find the Nearest Location to that user between these given nodes.

I have tried this query

```
UNWIND
["93049","67069","90762","86156","01067","18069","52146","04356"," 42329","53113","76131","40549","50670","50678","85774","80339"] AS plz
MATCH p=Shortestpath(
(a:plzNodes {plz: plz})-[*..14]-(b:plzNodes {plz: "88400"})
) RETURN  plz,collect(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [path expander procs](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/path-finding/path-expander/) from [APOC Procedures](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/) for this, collecting the possible end nodes, and then using the path expander from the start node to those end nodes with a limit of 1: the path to the first node encountered (which will be the shortest path, due to breadth first expansion) will be returned.

```
WITH ["93049","67069","90762","86156","01067","18069","52146","04356"," 42329","53113","76131","40549","50670","50678","85774","80339"] AS plzes
MATCH (a:plzNodes)
WHERE a.plz in plzes
WITH collect(a) as plzNodes
MATCH (b:plzNodes {plz: "88400"})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(b, {endNodes:plzNodes, limit:1, maxLevel:14}) YIELD node as closest
RETURN closest
```